# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'osgeo_utils'

Tags: python, osgeo

I am trying to run GDAL commands from a python script but I keep getting this error

```
from osgeo_utils.gdal_calc import *  # noqa
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'osgeo_utils'
```

If I try `pip install osgeo-utils` I then get more errors `note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip. hint: See above for output from the failure.`

How can I get it to install so that I can use my python code?